# EF6 transaction error in ObjectContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, transactions, entity-framework-6

please can someone help i'm trying to use Transaction in EF6. it's my first try in transaction in .net. 
i have read the manual by Microsoft in their site.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843.aspx and i would to use a transaction for user registration but nothing is working. Im using EF `objectContext`.
here is a little piece of my code :

```
using (var context= new MyModelContainer())
{ 
 using(var dbContextTransaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
      {
       try 
         {
          // code here to create user
          context.savechanges();
          // code here to add role
         context.savechanges();

         dbContextTransaction.Commit(); 
        }
      catch 
         {
         dbContextTransaction.Rollback(); 
         }
     }
}
```

My problem is that Visual Studio does not even recognize `Database.BeginTransaction()`. may be because we are using `objectContext`? i never use transaction. i change to use another database where our model is `DbContext` it's seems to work.

How can we use objectContext with transaction also (mean not distributed systems) ?
any tutorial please ?

I tried transaction scope but it's seem to work but i read that it's for distributed system ((( it's means that performance going down. any suggestion ? 
thanks for your time !!!

Answer (score 1):

Replace the line

```
using(var dbContextTransaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
```

with this:

```
using(var dbContextTransaction = new TransactionScope())
```

and remove the call to Rollback. [TransactionScore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope(v=vs.110).aspx) will do what you need.

TransactionScope is compatible with distributed systems, but if you do not make a call to other db's and use it as described, then it is more than good enough for your needs. If you try to make a call to save to another db (for example) then it will require special privileges and an exception will be thrown.

Comment: Thank for your answer ! I wrote in my text that Transaction Scope is working but i would like to know if it's the only way to do this with ObjectContext, because TansactionScope is usually use for distributed system ! i tried it already.

Comment: I just updated my answer before you commented. Transaction scope will not degrade performance. It simply escalates to a distributed transaction when you try to connect to **another** database to write or update entries.

Comment: We are using many databases. and in this transaction 2 of them should be use ( i just couldn't post all my code here but We create a user a db user, we save his personnal data in antother database, and add a new role to the first database if success. Thank for help.(I voted your answer up !)

Comment: In this case I believe that you are forced to use TransactionScope. You will also need to make some changes in your SQL server instances to accept distributed transactions - please see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174499(v=SQL.80).aspx. If my answer helped you please consider marking it as accepted.